# Dynamic timeout for each api in spring eureka

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

I am facing timeout problem while downloading excel reports from my web application. The application is follows microservices archtecture build using spring-cloud. The Api timed out as i had set the ribbon timeout to

```
ribbon.ReadTimeout= 40000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout= 40000
```

Now if i increase the timeout in application.properties, then it will be reflected in entire application. I need different timeout for UI and downloading reports.
Is there a way to set dynamic timeouts for different api's in spring cloud? Please guide

Comment: Try prefixing the setting with the service id

Comment: But i have to set different timeouts for different API's inside one service

Comment: yes, set the serviceId of the different api's. If it's the same service, then it can't be done with ribbon timeouts.

Comment: Any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Not automatically with spring cloud. You can certainly write custom code to do this per API rather than per service.